# What does this symbol means in Banach's spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be non trivial vector spaces such that $L(X,Y)$ is Banach's $\Rightarrow Y$ is Banach's.

I'm missing the definition of $L(X,Y)$ in my notes, also can you give me a hint? I'm new in Banach's spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$L(X,Y)$ is the space of linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. Frequently they are also assumed to be continuous, depending on the context. (In finite dimensions this distinction does not matter, but in infinite dimensions it does.)

Answer (score 0):

$L(X,Y)$ usually denotes the set of bounded (continuous linear maps.) In an infinite dimensional Banach space not all linear maps are bounded.